# Django - update_or_create

Tags: django, django-queryset

I've a model:-

```
class XYZ(models.Model):
    unique_col = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    total = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to update the total, given the `unique_col` value by `+10`. So, I do the following:-

```
try:
    obj = XYZ.objects.get(unique_col='unique_value')
    obj.total +=10
except:
    obj = XYZ(unique_col='unique_value', total=10)
finally:
    obj.save()
```

How can I update `total` to `+10` of previous value using `update_or_create` in this case?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you don't know the value of `total` in the event that `update_or_create` needs to create an object. If you specify a default value like so

```
class XYZ(models.Model):
    unique_col = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then you can run a get_or_create and do the update afterwards.

```
obj, created = XYZ.objects.get_or_create(unique_col='unique_value')
obj.total += 10
obj.save()
```

Granted this doesn't use the update_or_create method if you'd really like to use that, but it at least gets you out of needing the try/except, if that was what you were hoping to avoid

Comment: default should be 0 otherwise after creation it will contain the value 20

Comment: You should modify the definition of the object, it  will give you an error while saving.
obj, created = XYZ.objects.get_or_create(unique_col='unique_value')

Comment: I missed that, you're absolutely correct. I just updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

An updated answer for 2020:
The concept of Robert's answer is correct but I had to modify it in the following way to work for me:

Set default for total to zero:

```
class XYZ(models.Model):
    ...
    total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Set `obj, created` not just `obj`

```
obj, created = XYZ.objects.get_or_create(unique_col='unique_value')
obj.total += 10
obj.save()
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, "obj, created" is very important here

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to solve this is by using F expressions when updating the total field:

```
from django.db.models import F

obj, create = XYZ.objects.get_or_create(unique_col="unique_col")
obj.total = F('total') + 10
obj.save()
```

Django F expression [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

> An F() object represents the value of a model field or annotated
> column. It makes it possible to refer to model field values and
> perform database operations using them without actually having to pull
> them out of the database into Python memory.
>
> When Django encounters an instance of F(), it overrides the standard
> Python operators to create an encapsulated SQL expression;
>
> F() can be used on QuerySets of object instances, with update(). This
> reduces the two queries we were using before - the get() and the
> save() - to just one.
>
> F() therefore can offer performance advantages by:
> getting the database, rather than Python, to do work reducing the number of
> queries some operations require
>
> Another useful benefit of F() is that having the database - rather
> than Python - update a field’s value avoids a race condition.
>
> Django supports the use of addition, subtraction, multiplication,
> division, modulo, and power arithmetic with F() objects, both with
> constants and with other F() objects. Instead, Django uses the F()
> object to generate a SQL expression that describes the required
> operation at the database level.